# How to prove the following.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Let $\{_, _, _,\cdots \}$ be the sequence defined by the following recurrence relation:

• $_ = $

• $_ =  \times _{−} +$ for $ ≥ $

How to prove $_ = ^{+} − $ for any integer $ ≥ $?

Can anyone please help to prove this as I have no idea about this.

Comment: Hint: binary expansions.

Comment: Let $b_n=2^{n+1}-1$.  Show that $\{b_n\}$ satisfies the same recursion (and initial conditions).

Comment: Note: the title should give an idea of the content of the question, i.e. "proving a recursive formula" or something more descriptive would be better : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will show you how to get started on a proof by induction.

Base case: for $n=0$, we have $a_0=1$ by definition, and $2^{0+1}-1=1$.

Induction step: Suppose $a_k=2^{k+1}-1$ for some $k>0$. Then to complete the proof we wish to show that $a_{k+1}=2^{k+2}-1$.

Do you see how to finish the proof?

Comment: Can you also please explain the proof

Comment: Take the assumed value of $a_k$ from the induction step and plug it directly into the recursive formula $a_k =2a_{k-1}+1$. Simplify that expression and you will see that you get the desired result for $a_{k+1}$.

Comment: Then, what about 2^(n+1) -1. I am totally confused as they have given two things. Your help will be appreciated

Comment: The idea here in using proof by induction is that if it is true for a single value (the base case) and if the statement being true for $k$ implies that is is also true for $k+1$, then the statement must be true for all integers greater than the integer checked in the base case.

Comment: In response to the 'what about' question, what you are being asked to prove is that the recursive formula (that is, the two bullet points in your question) is the same as the formula $2^{n+1}-1$. When you do the proof by induction you prove that for all $k \geq 1$ the two formulas are equal. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Either you do as lulu wrote in the comments and prove that $\{b_n\}$ defined by $b_n=2^{n+1}-1$ satisfy the condition for the sequence $\{a_n\}$. Here, you need that a sequence is uniquely determined by a recursion with an initial condition.

Or you prove it by induction.

For the induction step, you have to prove
 $$
a_n=2a_{n-1}-1=\ldots=2^{n+1}-1
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to prove it, but it's far easier to follow @lulu's comment, or @Mundron's hint.

Suppose $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_ix^i$, then $$\begin{align}f(x)=a_0+(2a_0+1)x+(2a_1+1)x^2+\dots\\f(x)=a_0+2xf(x)+\frac{1}{1-x}-1\\f(x)=2xf(x)+\frac{1}{1-x}\\f(x)(1-2x)=\frac{1}{1-x}\\f(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-2x)}=-\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{2}{1-2x}\\f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)x^i+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}2^{i+1}x^i\end{align}$$

Comparing the coefficients of $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_ix^i$ with $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left (-1+2^{i+1}\right )x^i$ we conclude that $$a_n=2^{n+1}-1$$

Answer (score 0):

Alt. hint:   rewrite it in the following form, then telescope:

$$
a_i= 2 \cdot a_{i-1} + 1 \;\;\iff\;\; a_i + 1= 2 \big(a_{i-1} + 1 \big)=2^2\big(a_{i-2}+1\big) = \ldots  = 2^i \big(a_0+1\big) = 2^{i+1}
$$